# Wireless workaround for Xbox One controller on PC?

Tags: pc, controllers

### UPDATE

I found an off brand adaptor on ali-express that works just fine. It was about $20. Thanks for everyones help.

### ORIGINAL POST

I bought an Xbox One controller to use with my PC. It is a first generation controller that requires the wireless adapter to connect to a PC. This is annoying as it will cost me about the same price as a new controller ($40). This is a multi-tier question, as I am trying to find the best cost-ratio solution. For now I am playing via USB.

**Question 1:** Is there a Bluetooth hack for the first gen wireless controllers so I do not need to buy the proprietary adapter?

**Question 2:** Can the proprietary wireless adapter receive input from more than 1 controller? If so, I might as well buy a second first gen that has the adapter included and I'll have a second controller for player 2.

Comment: Yes it can; there is no way to make the controller you have support Bluetooth

Comment: This is the one time I'd suggest not buying off-brand stuff. I had a 'fake' adapter (for 360) that burnt out in about a week and didn't work very well anyway. IMO,PIDs either need to say Microsoft or Logitech on them.

Answer (score 2):

The first-gen Xbox One controllers are not Bluetooth-capable at all. It's fairly doubtful that there is a "hack" out there to add it in, as it would also entail writing device drivers for the controller or somehow adapting its output to be compatible with existing Bluetooth device drivers.

In any case, if there were a hack, it's pretty likely that the hassle and cost would far surpass that of buying and installing the officially-supported wireless adapter.

As for how many controllers the adapter supports, it depends on what OS you are using and what functionality you are looking for. All cases support at least 2 controllers (Windows 10 PC, with a stereo headset attachment, being the most restrictive). The most it can support is 8 (any Windows version down to 7, no headset attached).

More information on connecting an Xbox One controller to your PC, and the limitations of various configurations, is available on the Xbox website.

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/connect-xbox-one-controller-to-pc

Also FYI: It seems the Xbox Wireless Adapter for Windows is currently listed at about $25 USD (shipping may be extra).

http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/controllers/windows-wireless-adapter/

Comment: There isn't a hack, the controllers don't have the hardware, so "doubtfull" isn't specific enough of a dismissal of said hack.

Comment: @Ramhound Though far from trivial, it's not entirely inconceivable that someone could hack together some sort of a MicroUSB attachment based on a Raspberry Pi or something. Perhaps "doubtful" is understating it a bit, but at the same time it's not something that I believe is entirely beyond the realm of possibility. (i.e.: It may be possible that it could be done, but not likely that it has been.)

Comment: Suppose you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to make an Xbox controller communicate using Bluetooth (Xbox 360 included). Although newer Xbox One controllers allow Bluetooth through Windows 10.

In good news there is a limit of 8 controllers for the wireless adapter.

Comment: There are limits. And there are newer Xbox One controllers that use Bluetooth. http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/connect-xbox-one-controller-to-pc